# directory file import error in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

i am having file structure like

```
/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/voucher.py
/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/scrappers/quotes/quotes.py
i want to access voucher.py from quotes.py
```

i have tried these

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
from .. .. import api # ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/")
from api.voucher import Voucher
error i am getting is 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

Comment: `sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs")` maybe?

Comment: not working same error  no module named api,                                                              sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs")                                               from api import voucher

Answer (score 2):

You are at the right path, however..

It should be:

```
sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/")
from voucher import Voucher # or just import voucher
```

In the example I am showing you, `from voucher import Voucher` tries to import the `Voucher` class from `/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/voucher.py`.

Otherwise, in your way, you're trying to access `/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/api/voucher.py`.
Also, keep in mind that **there must be** an **__init.py__** file in the directories.

Comment: sys.path.append(/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/api/voucher.py)                   is it again needed to import like from voucher import Voucher                                         and creating the object for the class        or directly we can access the functions under the class

Comment: If `Voucher` is a class defined in `voucher.py`, then you with `import voucher` you can access it with `voucher.Voucher.method()`, while with `from voucher import Voucher` you can access the functions via `Voucher.method()`.

Comment: sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/voucher.py")                from voucher import Voucher                                                                                    still i am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voucher'

Comment: Why are you using `sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/voucher.py")`? I've explicitly told you in my answer, that it should be `sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/wep-rs/WEPR/weprs/api/")` and `from voucher import Voucher`. Please copy/paste if you have to..

Comment: No problem. You can accept my answer if it has worked.